# Scraping Netflix

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, netflix

Trying to get my last viewed data out of Netflix programmatically, but having some issues just with the login phase. My current code just causes Netflix to spit back a `We were unable to process your request.` page:

```
var request = require('request').defaults({jar: true});
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = "https://www.netflix.com/Login?locale=en-GB&nextpage=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.netflix.com%2FWiViewingActivity";

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var authCode = $("#login-form > input").attr("value");
        request.post(url+"?email=myemail%40gmail.com&password=mypassword&RememberMe=on&authURL="+authCode, {
        }, function(err, response, body){
            console.log(body);
        });
    }
})
```

Any ideas?

Surprisingly, there's next to nothing on Google for `Scraping Netflix`.

Comment: Are they using authentication cookies? There are better libraries for this in Java and Python. Try Ui4j or selenium. For nodejs, try https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver. Much of the time sites today will do more than provide a basic view state. You may need to process javascript. This could be apparent from the authcode requirement.

Comment: @Jazcash Also, if you do not have firebug and firefox I would recommend them. That, or wireshark. Use firebug to look for any remaining post parameters or other options. I am seeing more parameters than you have provided and the cheerio site structures your post differently. From my end it looks like you are submitting query parameters and not form data (e.g. http://www.netflix.com/q?key=value v. url:....,form:{key:value}) https://www.webniraj.com/2015/03/16/nodejs-scraping-websites-using-request-and-cheerio/

Comment: when I googled 'scraping netflix' I got 400K items. Isn't that enough? ;-) Good stuff above. Good luck!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out, needed to:

1. Send any sort of user-agent string
2. Send the form data using request's `form` param
3. Send the cookies manually

Here's my final code which gets the latest watched item:

```
var request = require('request').defaults({jar: true});
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = "https://www.netflix.com/Login";

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        var authCode = $("#login-form > input").attr("value");
        request.post({url: url, 
            form: {
                "email": "email@gmail.com",
                "password": "password",
                "authURL": authCode,
                "RememberMe": "on"
            },
            headers:{
                'User-Agent': "NodeScrape"
            }
        }, function(err, response, body){
            var cookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];
            request({url: "https://www.netflix.com/WiViewingActivity", headers: {'Cookie': cookies, 'User-Agent': "NodeScrape"}}, function(error, response, body){
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                console.log($(".seriestitle").eq(0).text());
            });
        });
    }
})
```